# What tools or techniques are available to analyze disk usage?

Tags: admin, documentum

We would like to analyze disk consumption within Documentum for possible business process improvement.  Can disk usage be determined by folder, by object type, by document filename extension, over time, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I think there are no other approaches for your task. It can only be solved by DQL query.

Let me describe why I think so: Documentum can store content files not only on filesystem but for example as BLOB in DB or as records in Centera and so on. So, Documentum should provide a unified approach for getting size for content files regardless of storing method. And this method is to store content size in attribute full_content_size of dmr_content object.
Also each dm_sysobject has attribute r_full_content_size where you can find size, in bytes,  of the first content object (dmr_content object) associated with sysobject.

So your DQL is correct only if each dm_sysobject in your system has only one associated content object.

Answer (score 2):

I know that I can roll my own DQL, for example:

```
select sum(r_full_content_size)/1024/1024/1024 as total_gb from dm_sysobject (all) where
cabinet('/My Cabinet',descend);
```

but I'm wondering if there are other approaches?  Tools analogous to UNIX du(1) command, etc.